# Break jq query string into lines

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

How can i break jq string into lines, this is for long lines, when i put "\" query breaks.

```
vpcExists=$(aws ec2 describe-vpcs --profile $profile | jq -r --arg vpcId "$vpcId" '.[][] | \
 select(.VpcId == $vpcId) \
| .["State"]' \
)
```

Comment: and no result with tutorials .....?

Comment: The newlines are shell specific features. Single quotes in bash will allow you to enter literal newlines fine... it's not jq specific.

Comment: thanks @JeffMercado that is confusing, but now i got it

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`jq` is fine with literal line breaks, so just add linefeeds anywhere without trying to escape them:

```
vpcExists=$(aws ec2 describe-vpcs --profile $profile |
    jq -r --arg vpcId "$vpcId" '
   .[][] 
     | select(.VpcId == $vpcId)
     | .["State"]' 
)
```

Here's a MCVE:

```
jq -r --arg vpcId "someId" '
   .[][] 
     | select(.VpcId == $vpcId)
     | .["State"]'  << 'EOF'


{ "Vpcs": [ {
            "VpcId": "someId",
            "InstanceTenancy": "default",
            "State": "available",
            "IsDefault": false
        } ] }
EOF
```

Comment: MCVE is Stack Overflow jargon for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. There's more details about that at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How to break up the query containing string interpolation?example:  "\(.foo)|\(.bar)"  Imagine that query is long and I would like to format it on mutiple lines