# How do I break a long string in jq in a bash command?

Tags: bash, shell, jq

Here's the minimal example:

```
echo "{\"foo\": \"John\",\"bar\":\"Smith\"}" | jq -r '@sh "export FOO=\(.foo)\nexport BAR=\(.bar) \n"'
```

And in my real life scenario case that `jq` selector is really long (think about 10 exports), how can I break them into multiple lines or something? I tried using `\` as a separator at the end of the lines but it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @oguzismail what do you mean?

Comment: For a more direct answer, see [Break jq query string into lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712545/break-jq-query-string-into-lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would probably do:

```sh
. <(
  jq -r '"export "+(to_entries|map((.key|ascii_upcase)+"="+(.value|@sh))|.[])'\
    <<<'{"foo":"John","bar":"Smith"}'
)
```

Alternative with one export for all variables:

```sh
. <(
  jq -r '
    "export"+(
      to_entries|
        map(
            " " +
            (.key|ascii_upcase) +
            "=" +
            (.value|@sh)
          ) | add
        )
  ' <<<'{"foo":"John","bar":"Smith"}'
)
```

You may also consider filtering-out replacing characters within `.key` strings so they are always valid shell variable identifiers.